# How to force Visual Studio 2022 create console projects with namespaces and classes (like in old good days)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Just switched to VS2022, created new project and see this:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Where is all other stuff? Why is that by default now?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022

Comment: Previously all that stuff was necessary, now it isn't. This is the minimum code that's needed to write a string to the console..

Comment: @phuzi sure it is a nice new development, but I don't like it either. It's C#, not Python.

Comment: @phuzi I understand that it is not necessary, but almost any program need arguments parsing. So now I had to write that staff by hand from scratch or what?

Comment: @CodeCaster almost any program need arguments parsing. So now I had to write that staff by hand from scratch every time? What the hell MS was thinking about when doing this?

Comment: No need to do it everytime. You could create yourself a template that you can use for your console projects in the future.

Comment: Read the first section of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates

Comment: you can create a project with .net5 as the target and then change it manually to .net 6 so that you can use the new features.

Comment: Quick fix, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Doomdied.ClassicConsole1

Comment: I consider switching to 5 and then back to 6 a dirty hack :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is an option now, to disable `top-level statements`:

[image]

I just tried it and it produces an old-style project. :-)
You also don't loose `file-scoped namespaces`, they still work.

Comment: This should be acepted answer now. I works for any kind of project, not only console applications. (Thank you MS for this check, now make it checked by default).

Answer (score 6):

Click the link. It redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates. It has a paragraph stating:

> If you want to use the old templates, see the [Use the old program style](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style) section.

That section mentions that this is the new default. To circumvent it, create a .NET 5-targeting application, and modify your project file:

```
-   <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
+   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

A workaround I guess would be to create a custom project template.

Comment: Well the thing is - I want to use dotnet 6.0 with old-style format. The is no main method, no arguments, not namespace - nothing. All that stuff is needed to be written by hand now or what?

Comment: No, it's generated by convention on compilation. You don't _need_ `using System; namespace Foo { class Program { void Main(string[] args) {` anymore.

Comment: I need args. Where to find them now without writing main method?

Comment: @AlekDepler You can still use `args` in the new template.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer... simply, you can create a project with .net5 as the target and then change it manually to .net 6 so that you can use the new features.

Comment: So unless you give in to Microsoft's dumb new way of doing things, you can't use .NET 6?  Why not force people to run Windows 11 while they're at it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can install the Classic Console Template
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Doomdied.ClassicConsole1

It add old classic console back, then you can forgot the new one.
[image]

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but what's the difference to disabling top-level statements?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 6 uses a new template when creating a C# console app. The new template reduces the amount of boilerplate code necessary to write a simple C# program. I believe this change was meant to benefit beginning programmers and those who are new to C#.

New style:

- Statements in Program.cs that appear outside of any function are automatically placed in `Main()`.
- Function declarations are moved outside `Main()` and made static.
- A number of using statements are implicitly added for common namespaces like System, System.IO, System.Linq, etc.

Example:

```
// New style

Console.WriteLine("Code in Main()");
Test();

void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
// Old style

using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Code in Main()");
            Test();
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

There is nothing stopping you from using the old style. You can copy and paste the old-style code above into Program.cs, and it will run just fine.

Comment: This dumb template only creates confusion for the beginner and experienced alike. The old template makes the entry points, declarations and the structure of your program clear, where as this dumb template hides all the important ceremony from you. This wouldn't be a bad template for a REPL, but for regular development its horrible.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the `args` through a special variable with that name in a top level statement class file:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Argument={arg}");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No arguments");
}
```

Similarly, you just return an int to set the exit code:

```
string? s = Console.ReadLine();

int returnValue = int.Parse(s ?? "-1");
return returnValue;
```

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

As to why, there has been a push to clean up the source files from needless whitespace, masses of curly braces, long lists of imports at the top of each file and the explicit namespace declaration, where most everyone syncs the namespaces with the assembly name and solution folder anyway.

It's been a thorn in the eye of many that simple things in c# need 10s of lines of code where they are a single line in node or python or ruby. It's just not productive. Same for Razor templates and Razor files. You just need an IDE to do she right thing. With these changes it should become much easier to be productive from the GitHub, even if you're not using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The "other stuff" is all there; it's just a new convention. It isn't obvious as you might use to get things in C# but this is the new way. And of course, you can use the old style with `Main(string args)` by selecting **Do no use top-level statements** checkbox when creating the project in Visual Studio or employ the `--use-program-main` option on the command line, like this:

```
dotnet new console --use-program-main
```

As for the magic of accessing the command line arguments with this new style, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918647/how-to-access-command-line-arguments-with-new-console-app-template-in-vs2022).