# How to access command line arguments with new Console App template in VS2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wonder how one can access the command line arguments, given this is all that gets generated in the `Program.cs` file by the new template for Console Application in Visual Studio 2022:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Moreover, there is no `args` variable in scope.

So how to access CLI arguments?

Comment: You could still use the style of the old templates. This is just a shortcut for the easiest of cases. And the easiest of cases is without arguments.

Comment: The docu states that args should still be there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

Comment: [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911575/16764901)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently one needs to add some code to fireup the IntelliSense. I.e., if you try to access `args` as a first thing in your program you'll be supprised (like myself):

[image: No args shown in IntelliSense]

[image: args causes compile error]

---

However, couple of lines later:

[image: args appear]

Voila!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the old style and check the "`Do not use top-level statements`" while creating the project:

[image]

This way you'd have the good old main with the explicit arguments. You can also possibly add the scaffolding after the fact.