# go back to the old template Visual Studio Code C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, visual-studio-code

Hi i'm learning c# but when i run my first app with visual studio code i've this code

```
    // See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

How can i go back to the old template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Visual Studio 2022 create console projects with namespaces and classes (like in old good days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911480/how-to-force-visual-studio-2022-create-console-projects-with-namespaces-and-clas)

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 6, it has changed. Anyways, [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style) out the documents about these template changes.

Comment: yes target .net6 "vscode"

Comment: @user9859592 please read the documents in the link I provided above.

Comment: it is not clear how to do it!

Comment: @user9859592 I'm not sure how it could be any more clear, what are you confused about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the easiest way to do it:

1. Create a new console application targeting **.NET5**
2. Right click on your project and find *Edit project file*. Click into that.
3. Optional: Change `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>` to
   `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`
4. Save changes.

Done. By taking those steps, you start with the old template and if you *want* to target the new .NET6 framework, step 3 is how you can do that.

Edit: Optionally, steps 2 & 3 can also be done as follows:

2. Right click on your project and click on *Properties*
3. Optional: Under tabs `Application` > `General` find `Target framework`. Click the dropdown and choose **.NET6**