# How to use functions in vs 2022 if there is no Main function

Tags: c#

How to use functions in vs 2022 if there is no Main function

I tried writing the Main function myself but nothing worked

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911480/how-to-force-visual-studio-2022-create-console-projects-with-namespaces-and-clas

Comment: there is a accessible `args` variable as the old Main function.

Comment: "I tried writing the Main function myself but nothing worked" - it would have helped if you'd shown us what you tried, and what happened. But you can still write the whole class declaration as before. Basically, without knowing what problem you're facing, it's impossible to help - please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: "nothing worked" is not acceptable description. What errors You have, and show how You try code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 9.0 or higher writing main function is not necessary.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

So, just something like that:

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("**** sample ****");
SimpleArrays();
static void SimpleArrays()
{
    Console.WriteLine("=> Simple Array Creation");
    int[] myInts = new int[3];
    string[] booksOnDotNet = new string[100];
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

UPD: Also, probably you should choose an entry point of app in project properties. (Bc programm can have multipy main methods)

Or, maybie you just forgot to select your project in solution explorer. Just RMB on project and select it as current

Comment: Without knowing what error the OP is actually facing, you're just guessing. At the moment we don't know anything about what they've tried or what happened, other than "but nothing worked". When a question is unclear, please request more information rather than just guessing.