# How to do declaration in Visual studio 2022 if Top level statement is enabled?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, declaration

I could only see `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World")` in Visual studio 2022. When referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911480/how-to-force-visual-studio-2022-create-console-projects-with-namespaces-and-clas), the good old structure can be brought back, but question is, in this new template, how can we declare some fields, variable, constants etc, which can be used in `Main()`.

For ex, I want to declare `int number1 = 5;` and then use it in `Main` method execution.

Comment: If you want anything other than a Main method, just declare the full class. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve... (Where would you use `number1` outside Main? How would you expect any other code to be included in the same class?)

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I want to use it inside the main method. If I consider Console.WriteLine is executed inside `main`. Then I to declare it outside main(). Sorry, bit confused since it does not have this `class` structure

Comment: "Then I to declare it outside main()." What do you mean? *Why* do you want to declare it outside Main? What difference do you expect that to make, vs making it a local variable in Main? Please clarify your question - until it's clear what you're trying to do and why, I don't expect anyone will be able to help you.